# How would I only print out characters that have not appeared before in an argument?

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out a way to only print out the characters without getting duplicates in C. Any help is appreciated.

For example, if i pass in 'Hello', i would like 'Helo' returned.

My current code that just prints out the passed in argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (argv[1][i] != '\0')
    {
        putchar(argv[1][i]);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Edit: preferably without the use of any extra functions / #includes’s

Comment: You have to store the printed elements and compare every time before next printing.

Comment: @SouravGhosh No need to store them. Just compare with all previous. I.e. `for (j = 0; j < i; j++) { if (argv[1][j] == argv[1][i]) { doPrint = false; break; }}`.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen only useful if `i` is a lower number...

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I don't follow you... What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. You need an array with the length of the [max possible ascii code](https://theasciicode.com.ar/), to handle the *seen* characters. Hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int * seen = calloc(256, sizeof(char));

    if (argv[1] == NULL) {

        printf("No argument.\n");

        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < strlen(argv[1]) ; i++) {

        if (seen[argv[1][i]] != 1) {

            seen[argv[1][i]] = 1;

            putchar(argv[1][i]);
        }
    }

    free(seen);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    char f[128];
    unsigned char ch;
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("use : ./a.out str");
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i != sizeof(f); ++i)
        f[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        ch = argv[1][i];
        if (f[ch] == 0) {
            putchar(ch);
            f[ch] = 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And here we have a textbook example of a buffer overflow vulnerability.

Comment: I'm sorry, what?@SaniSinghHuttunen

Comment: Try using any extended ASCII characters (i.e. ASCII codes > 127) and you'll be out of bounds of the `f`-array.

Comment: @YunbinLiu Buffer overflows are explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow